# Manually saving ModelForm relative foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, foreign-keys

Below is simplified example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # some data, does not really matter

class ProductAttributeValue(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')

    value=models.CharField(_("value"),max_length=100)
```

....

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        #Here, I am dynamically constructing and injecting attributes.
        #my products have dynamic attributes
        # the filled-in values of these attributes need to be saved as ProductAttributeValue instances
        #...


    def save(commit):
        m = super(ProductForm, self).save(commit=False)

        #looping thru my custom attributes and constructing instances
        #to simplify I will just put one example
        attr_val=ProductAttributeValue(product=m)
        attr_val.value=self.clean_data['myval']
        m.productattributevalue_set.add(attr_val)

        if commit:
            m.save()

        # also doing m2m_save if exists

        return m
```

So as I was expecting this fails with product_id=None error. I also tried to understand how django's InlineForm (on admin side) work, but seems they are saving the main Product first and then the ProductAttributeValue, and if say ProductAttributeValue saving fails they are fine.
For my case it's not acceptable, i.e. either I should save all the form (both product and the value) or fail. I can certainly save with commit=True from the beginning but as I said, I don't want a case where product is saved and value not.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Of course you can't add an unsaved instance to another unsaved instance. What's wrong with calling `save()` then assigning the attribute? Do you expect it to fail somehow? If you do, then there's an answer below about transactions. I'm just curious why you're expecting failure here.. you should be doing validation beforehand to ensure it doesn't fail at the database level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/
I think you can do this using a manual transaction.  Commit the first save and then rollback if the second fails:

```
@transaction.commit_manually
def viewfunc(request):
    ...
    # You can commit/rollback however and whenever you want
    transaction.commit()
    ...

    # But you've got to remember to do it yourself!
    try:
       ...
    except:
       transaction.rollback()
    else:
       transaction.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was curious to see whether there were any other solutions. I already use transaction.commit_on_success in couple of places. I guess it allows to avoid manual rollback/commit calls.

Answer (score 0):

Since no id is generated for your Product until it is saved, I don't think you'll be able to save attributes before the product.  At any rate, one must be saved before the others -- might as well save the Product first, then save the attributes, and add some logic to delete the Product if saving ProductAttributeValues fails for some reason.  I don't see why save would fail on the ProductAttributeValues anyway, though, as validation should already have been done in clean.